# date picker jquery plugin not working in another page via jquery load method

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-load

I have two html main.html and a.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title> main.html   </title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#y").click(function()
     {
       $('#y1').load('a.html');
     });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="y">link1    </div>
  <div id="y1">frame   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

a.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>a.html    </title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#date").datepicker();
      $("#y2").on("click",function(){
          alert("clicked data in a.html");
      });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="y2"> click here to get alert   </div>
  <input id="date" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

when I open a.html file the datepicker works good, 
but open main.html file click 'link1' to load the a.html into main.html
datepicker fails and I get a error message in firefox error console as

```
>Error: TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
>Source File: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js?_=1362478481277
>Line: 605
```

[EDITIED to improve my question below]

now my main.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title> main.html   </title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#y").click(function()
     {
       $('#y1').load('a.html');
     });
     $("#y4").click(function()
     {
       $('#y1').load('b.html');
     });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="y">link1    </div>
  <div id="y4">link2    </div>
  <div id="y1">frame   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

a.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>a.html    </title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#date").datepicker();
      $("#y2").on("click",function(){
          alert("clicked data in a.html");
      });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="y2"> click here to get alert   </div>
  <input id="date" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

b.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>b.html    </title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#date1").datepicker();
      $("#y3").on("click",function(){
          alert("clicked data in b.html");
      });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="y3"> click here to get alert   </div>
  <input id="date1" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
```

to your main.html page

Ok, read this tutorial: http://webtutsdepot.com/2009/06/13/ajax-page-loading-with-jquery/

> Important: When you load a page into another page the page you load
>   will get the styles from the current page, this means that all you
>   need to have in the page you want to load is what goes inside the
>    tags.

So you need to load all your script files in your main.html page and all you need in other pages is

*edit Changed main.html and a.html to reflect your question, this sould solve your problems with script conflict

main.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title> main.html   </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#y").click(function()
    {
       $('#y1').load('a.html #calendar'
       , function() {
            $("#date").datepicker();
            $("#y2").on("click",function(){
                alert("clicked data in a.html");
            });
       });
    });

    $("#y4").click(function()
    {
       $('#y1').load('b.html #calendar'
       , function() {
            $("#date1").datepicker();
            $("#y3").on("click",function(){
                alert("clicked data in b.html");
            });
       });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="y">link1    </div>
  <div id="y4">link2    </div>
  <div id="y1">frame   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

a.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>a.html</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='calendar'>   
  <div id="y2"> click here to get alert   </div>
  <input id="date" type="text" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#date").datepicker();

      $("#y2").on("click",function(){
      alert("clicked data in a.html");
      });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes .. Thanks it worked...  but still I have a problem.
This might sound weird ..
Now for the first time link1 is clicked date picker popped up.
second time click link1 again the same error.

I have planned to have link2 as well (loading b.html) with the date picker. so if I click link2 date picker not popping up and same error :(

Comment: Check this out .. http://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution It says scripts will run from the loading page too if I am not wrong

Comment: If I add the script in to main.html I get the following error
...

Error: TypeError: inst is undefined
Source File: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js?_=1362480888009
Line: 8513

Comment: Thanks for your time .. but this will not solve my problem coz when I open a.html alone it will not work :( I use firefox

Comment: ok, then you leave your scripts in a.html, but you also need to include them in main.html if you wan't to use .load in main page. I've edited code, now it should work when you load you page and open it alone.

Comment: I have updated my question to help you better ... This is what I finally need ... All main.html and a.html and b.html should work independently

Comment: Thanks works perfectly !!!..... What if I have more scripts in the a.html file ?? any easy way to link that here... ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, solved using a previous version of "JQuery-UI". In my case goes to use the version 1.9.2 and 1.10.3 to "JQuery" version 1.10.1. Know the reason, but I think the latest versions bring some problems compactness, so I chose to use always backward to the past.
I hope it will be useful